# SQL List total orders in descending order

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

```
SELECT Customer.CID, Count(Order.OrderID) AS [# Orders]
FROM Customer INNER JOIN [Order] ON Customer.CID = Order.CID
Group By Customer.CID DESC;
```

Im trying to list the total number of orders by customer in descending order. I get a syntax error on the group by clause. Im not sure what the syntax error is.

Comment: what's error are you getting?

Comment: "Syntax error in Group By clause"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing your ORDER BY clause. Your query should look like:

```
SELECT Customer.CID, Count(Order.OrderID) AS [# Orders]
FROM Customer INNER JOIN [Order] ON Customer.CID = Order.CID
GROUP BY Customer.CID
ORDER BY Customer.CID DESC;
```

Comment: Btw, the query works, but I like to avoid using reserved words like `Order` as object names.

Comment: If i want to order it by the number of orders how could i do that?

Comment: ORDER BY Order.OrderID DESC;

Answer (score 1):

You should use `order by` instead of `group by`.
So your new query will be,

```
SELECT Customer.CID, Count(Order.OrderID) AS [# Orders]
FROM Customer INNER JOIN [Order] ON Customer.CID = Order.CID
Order By Customer.CID DESC;
```

I don't have tables. so please provide your remark.

Comment: If i want to order it by the number of orders how could i do that?

Comment: Your query won't work for the user. You need to use group by & order by. Look at my answer for clarification.