# MS Access SQL orders in a specific month

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT ItemCategory.Category, Sum(OrderItem.Quantity)
FROM (ItemCategory INNER JOIN Inventory ON ItemCategory.Category = Inventory.Category)       
INNER JOIN ([Order] INNER JOIN OrderItem ON Order.OrderID = OrderItem.OrderID) ON    
Inventory.ItemID = OrderItem.ItemID
Where Order.OrderDate LIKE MONTH(June)
Group By ItemCategory.Category;
```

Im trying to find the total quantity ordered in june. the query that I made above results in no results when there should be.

Is there a problem in my logic?

Comment: show table schema and sample data too

Comment: Are you sure that you need the category field? Why? Are you trying to sum by category also?

Comment: Related if not dup. ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/16370814/1369235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your where clause with this...

```
Where DatePart('m',Order.OrderDate)=6
```

Its not good practice to use reserved keywords like order as your table or column name.